# At what stage of human development does a person attain secondary consciousness?

Tags: consciousness

In regards to Gerald Edelman's definition on consciousness, at what stage of human development would a person attain secondary consciousness apart from their existing primary consciousness? Could this transition be directly observed or measured?

Primary Consciousness is defined as: "the ability, found in humans and some animals, to integrate observed events with memory to create an awareness of the present and immediate past of the world around them." [1]

Secondary Consciousness is defined as: "an individual's accessibility to their history and plans... and includes such features as self-reflective awareness, abstract thinking, volition and metacognition." [2]

Sources: 
A .pdf of Gerald M. Edelman's paper "Naturalizing consciousness: a theoretical framework" can be found [HERE](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4d98/b9b68becf6803f09cfc801e2eacdb4899b1c.pdf?_ga=2.156657595.1864117924.1563476579-17106181.1563476579)

Wikipedia:

[1] [Primary Consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_consciousness)

[2] [Secondary Consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_consciousness)

Comment: Some links and quotes have been included for clarity.

Comment: This seems to be a better fit for cognitive science SE ....